# Why a stem '%' is not expanded by GNU Make within a 'patsubst' function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
A = a
B = b
FOO = A B
BAR = $(FOO:%=$(%))
C = c
FOO += C

all:
    echo $(BAR)
```

I expected `make` to print `a b c`, but it doesn't (the stem '%' is not expanded or something). I tried changing the assignment of `BAR` for:

`$(eval BAR = $(FOO:%=$$(%)))`

but it only prints `a b` (as it should be because `eval` immediately performs the substitution using the current value of `FOO`).

So what's wrong with the definition of `BAR` and how can I change it so that `make` prints `a b c` (without moving any of the other lines, of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is a perfectly valid variable name (although should be avoided for obvious reasons), so the substitution expression `$(FOO:%=$(%))` simply substitutes each token in `FOO` with the value of the variable `%`, which is empty - make must expand `$(%)` before it can perform the substitution.

`BAR = $(foreach v,$(FOO),$($v))` is one way you could solve this.